# Compilation of several projects at once

Tags: compiling, makefile, recursion

I search a way to (re)compile several different projects at once
(all assumed to be compile individually without error). 
Here, I present the context and the problem.

The context:

I have a topic, e.g. "Sciences", and wrote several projects to it (articles, papers).
They all share a same template directory containing the skeleton main file, 
a "Settings" folder, an "Article" folder, an "Images" folder and a "Vocabulary" folder, set as follow:

```
/my/path/Topic/TeX-Template/
        Settings/
              packages.sty
              settings.sty
              macros.sty
        /Images/
              image.ewm.eps
        Vocabulary/
              vocabulary.sty
        Articles/
        topic-main.tex
        topic-corpus.tex
```

- vocabulary.sty is a collection of project specific macros, i.e. \newcommand{\technicaltermA}{technical term A}.
- topic-main.tex contains the base of the document (\documentclass{...}, etc.)
- topic-corpus.tex contains the skeleton of the project (organized by \intput{./file.tex} lines).
- Articles directory is empty, it will contains the section's files of the project, and input-ed in the topic-corpus.tex

Then, there's a little script "topic.sh" included in my $PATH that says:

```
cp -a $TOPIC/*tex .
cp -a $TOPIC/Articles
ln -s $TOPIC/Settings 
ln -s $TOPIC/Images
ln -s $TOPIC/Vocabulary
```

Of course, I created a bash variable $TOPIC pointing to /my/path/Topic/Topic-Template

Once I created a NewProject folder in which I executed the script, I rename the "topic-" files to "newprojectname-".

I have then many projects in the Sciences folder, for example ScienceA, ScienceB and ScienceC. They all are correctly compiled.

Now the problem:
I need to correct a term "technical term A" appearing in all projects, provided by a "\technicaltermA" macro from the vocabulary.sty. Therefore, I modify the macro.

how do I apply the correction to **all** projects at once, without having to go in each folder and compile manually? 
It would require the program to jump into each folder, and compile each project with its own -main.tex file.

(Edit: `<dt>` removed...)

Comment: Welcome! What is with all the `<dt>` etc.? Maybe I'm missing the concept.... As the answer you've got indicates, this really isn't TeX-specific. You don't have to use `make` to solve it, but any solution is likely to be along those lines i.e. depend on what's available on your system *outside* TeX Live or MikTeX or whatever you use. A `make` solution is worth doing if you expect to do this a lot. Or you can write a script yourself, if it is rarer and that's easier for you. Or, if it is a one-time thing, you can just use the facilities provided by your shell directly to loop through them.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a tex question, but a general compilation question. Essentially, you have to write a makefile in each directory saying how each *-main.tex is compiled.
Then you have to write a root makefile which executes make in each of the subdirectories, along the following lines:

```
.PHONY: all default clean realclean ...

default:
    @for i in `ls | egrep "(Sciences)|(Arts)|..."`; do { $(MAKE) default -C $$i; } done
...
```

Yes, this is tedious. But if you provide the right dependencies, make will take care of the rest.